# ListView customization on button click

Tags: android, listview

I have a Custom listview and a custom adapter.the layout is like this:

[image]

Now, I have a checkbox which is hidden by default(defined in customlistlayout). I want it to appear when the user presses delete button.

I tried by setting  `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`in button onclicklistener, but the app crashes.
How can i achieve this. Thanks for the Help

```
Log Cat`12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681): Process: com.testing.callreminder, PID: 18681
12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681):    at com.testing.callreminder.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:130)
12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
12-23 22:27:54.236: E/AndroidRuntime(18681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
```

OnClickListener implementation for the layout:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btn_add :
        Intent next = new Intent("com.testing.callreminder.ADDITEM");
        startActivity(next);

        break;
    case R.id.btn_delete:
        chk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;


    default:
        chk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;

    }       
}
```

CustomAdapter

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    boolean i;
    Context c;
    ArrayList<MenuListItems> menuList;

    public MenuListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MenuListItems> list){
        c=context;
        menuList=list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return menuList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return menuList.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public void setCheckBoxVisibility(boolean visible) {
        i = visible;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuListItems menuListItems = menuList.get(position);

          if (convertView == null) {
               LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist, parent, false);

              }
          if(i){
              CheckBox ck = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delBox);
              ck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              notifyDataSetChanged();

          }
                TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvhide);
                id.setText(menuListItems.getSlno());
              TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
              title.setText(menuListItems.getTitle());
              TextView phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvpnumber);
              phone.setText(menuListItems.getPhone());

              return convertView;
        }
}
```

Comment: please provide some code and the stack trace (why the app is crashing)

Comment: Post your logcat error trace

Comment: @sockeqwe and Rohit posted

Comment: Check line 130 in MainActivity.java ... I guess the variable chk is null!

Comment: @sockeqwe 130 is chk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE), i dont know why its throwing an error

Comment: chk is not initialized! Post the code where do you setup chk. Probably you have a typo when you use findViewById() or you simply have another id in your xml layout and assign the wrong one

Comment: chk = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.delBox); it is initialised and id is correct.

Comment: Where do you set the OnClickListener? Please add that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method on your adapter like "setCheckBoxVisibility(boolean visible);" inside this method you will save the boolean value into a private field and call notifyDataSetChanged(); In your getView method you will check this field and set the visibility.

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
boolean i;
boolean showCheckbox;
Context c;
ArrayList<MenuListItems> menuList;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MenuListItems> list){
    c=context;
    menuList=list;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return menuList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return menuList.get(position);

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public void setCheckBoxVisibility(boolean visible) {
    i = visible;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify dataset changed here

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuListItems menuListItems = menuList.get(position);

      if (convertView == null) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
             .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist, parent, false);

          }
      if(i){
          CheckBox ck = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delBox);

          if(i)
              ck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          else
              ck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
            TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvhide);
            id.setText(menuListItems.getSlno());
          TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
          title.setText(menuListItems.getTitle());
          TextView phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvpnumber);
          phone.setText(menuListItems.getPhone());

          return convertView;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I am new to this, can u please explain further with a snippet or so? please?

Comment: I'll try, sorry my bad English. The Checkbox is not in activity but in the ListViewItem, you need to loop through all the items in your listview and change one by one. Making the way I showed is simpler because you only recharges your listview and the getView method is responsible for the change.

Comment: Now on your onClick call the method like that

case R.id.btn_delete:
   myAdapter.setCheckBoxVisibility(true);
        break;

Comment: One more problem, now if i select first listitem and scroll down for next set, the first item in the next set is getting checked automatically.how do i resolve?

Comment: Yes android reuse the same View for performance, the best way to improve this is store the checked value in your MenuListItems instance. Create a property and use your value like that ck.setChecked(menuListItems.getChecked());

Comment: wat do i write in getChecked? how should i start?